# Pigeonhole Principle Problem with $5$ people, can't be the case that there are $3$ strangers or $3$ acquaintances.

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

Show that it is possible to have a set of $5$ people such that there is no subgroup of $3$ strangers or a subgroup of $3$ people known to one another in the set.

I drew a little graph and came up with an example where there was no subgroup of $3$, either connected (people know each other) or disconnected (strangers). The problem said to show that this situation was possible. However, how do I use the pigeonhole principle for this? I'm sure I'm using it without even knowing, I just want to see how it is applied in this problem. Any solutions or hints are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the example you found a cycle graph?

Comment: It is two $5$-cycles. One solid line for acquaintances and one dotted for strangers.

Comment: To show something is possible, coming up with one example is sufficient.

Comment: @RobertTheTutor I agree, I just wanted to know how to use The Pigeonhole Principle for this.

Comment: @ddswsd: It isn’t really a pigeonhole principle problem. The pigeonhole principle will come in when you prove (or see a proof) that with $6$ (or more) people there always are $3$ strangers or $3$ acquaintances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two graphs that you consider. One is the acquaintance graph, and the other is a stranger graph. The two graphs are complement graphs. We know that there are $\binom{5}{2}=10$ total edges that may be split between these graphs. Let's call these $G_1,G_2$

Let $A$ be some node in the graph Each node has a total of 4 total edges incident on it. We can choose to split these edges in $G_1,G_2$ in either $\{1,3\}$ or $\{2,2\}$ ways.

If we split as $\{1,3\}$, then call the 3 adjacent nodes in $G_2$ to $A$ as ${B,C,D}$. Then none of ${B,C,D}$ can have edges in $G_2$ between themselves. If they do, they would form a triangle back to $A$. But this means they have edges between themselves in $G_1$. Thus they form a triangle or a 3-clique in $G_1$ violating the constraint.

Thus each node has $\{1,3\}$ edges incident on it in both $G_1,G_2$ (as the $\{1,3\}$ case was violated). Further, we have a total of 10 edges between $G_1,G_2$. Since the constraints are symmetric, the graphs may contain 5 edges each. Since each node contains 2 edges with a total of 5 edges, we get a 5-cycle.

A 5 cycle, happily turns out to be [self complementary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_graph#Self-complementary_graphs_and_graph_classes)

EDIT: See [here](http://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs103/cs103.1184/lectures/11/Small11.pdf) for details on how pigeon hole principle may be used in a related question of 6 people